Torch not compiled with CUDA enabledを直したい
RTX3050
Visual Studio Build Tool2022　C++によるデスクトップ開発にチェックした
python3.10、3.12でもダメ
NVIDIA Studio ドライバー 552.22 | Windows 11
CUDAtoolkit12.4
PytorchはVersion: 2.5.1+cu124(pytorchはpipでダウンロード) 
nvidia-smi出たときではCUDA Version: 12.4
環境変数CUDAtoolkitCUDAHOMEとCUDAPATHに
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.4と設定したのにTorch not compiled with CUDA enabledでした。
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())  # TrueであればCUDAが利用可能
これはtrueです
print(torch.cuda.device_count()) # 利用可能なGPUの数
1になってます

Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled は何をどう実行して表示されたものでしょうか？ torch.cuda.is_available() が True であれば特に問題ないはずで、肝心の質問したい部分が書かれていないように思われます。加えて、PyTorchインストール時の手順も重要ですので、そこも補足されるべきです。

学習を実行された際にGPUが使われないってことなのでしょうか？課題は何なのでしょうか？
